# Turn a time-point column into intervals

Tags: python, r, tidyverse, intervals, tibble

I have a tibble storing time-point data:

```
data.frame(Time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), readings = c(123, 234, 145, 234, 121))
```

and I would like to turn it into a table like the following:

| From | To | Initial | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 123 | 234 |
| 1 | 2 | 234 | 145 |
| 2 | 3 | 145 | 234 |
| 3 | 4 | 234 | 121 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I prefer to accomplish it in R/ tidyverse, but if python can do it in a much simpler way, I can also adopt some python codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(To = lead(Time), End = lead(readings)) %>% 
       select('From' = Time, To, 'Initial' = readings, End)
  From To Initial End
1    0  1     123 234
2    1  2     234 145
3    2  3     145 234
4    3  4     234 121
```

Answer (score 3):

We may do this in `base R` by removing the last row and first row of the dataset and renaming the columns

```
setNames(cbind(df1[-nrow(df1), ], df1[-1, ]),
     c("From", "Initial", "To", "End"))[c(1, 3, 2, 4)]
  From To Initial End
1    0  1     123 234
2    1  2     234 145
3    2  3     145 234
4    3  4     234 121
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `dplyr` approach: using `across`

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), lead, .names="end_{col}")) %>% 
  select(From=Time, To=end_Time, Initial=readings, End=end_readings)
```

```
  From To Initial End
1    0  1     123 234
2    1  2     234 145
3    2  3     145 234
4    3  4     234 121
5    4 NA     121  NA
```